# Selecting rows in a table and replacing them with the new data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with headers:

```
<table id="my-table">
    <thead>
        <th>header1</th>
        <th>header2</th>  
        <th>header3</th>  
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>data1</td>
         <td>data2</td>
         <td>data3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I select only rows and replace them with the new data using jQuery? Only rows and not headers.

Comment: ```$('tbody > tr')``` will only select rows in the table's body (not the headers).

Comment: `$('tbody').find('tr')` should be faster. But why your `th` is not wrapped inside `tr` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the context of the jquery selector as well...

```
$("tr", "#my-table tbody").each(function (i, item) {
    $("td", this).each(function () {
        // do something with the td.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems obvious, I would try this

```
$("#my-table tbody tr")
```

Or this

```
$("#my-table tr:has(td)")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $('#my-table tbody tr td').each(function(){//to select all rows in the table with id my-table
   $(this).text('test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tr').not('thead tr').addClass('selected').
```